# Prevent user from deleting himself

Tags: delphi

When users log in, their name is displayed in the statusbar in the mainform of the application :

> StatusBar1.Panels[1].Text:= 
>   DataModule1.ADQuery4.FieldByName('USER').AsString;

However, this user also has access (priviledge) to another form through which it is possible to add or remove users). How can I prevent this user from deleting himself ? How can I tell a query that adds users to avoid the one displayed in the statusbar? Or perhaps a message before delete ?

Comment: Which DBMS do you use ? Could you include a tag with this information in your question ?

Comment: Before you can hope to continue you need to give things names. You can't hope to get anywhere with things ADQuery4. Then you'll need to define what you mean by "delete users".

Comment: sqlite....delete users means you are able to remove the user from the system. They can no longer access the application.Obvious?

Comment: I'd be more worried of a user deleting other users than deleting themselves.

Comment: Only users with appropriate permission can do that...but you have a point there..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the BeforeDelete event of ADQuery4.

```
procedure TDataModule1.ADOQuery4BeforeDelete(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
 if (ADQuery4.FieldByName('USER').AsString=StatusBar1.Panels[1].Text) then abort;
end;
```

Instead of abort you can raise an exception. Also note that the above code presumes that the field 'USER' is unique in your data base. By the way to avoid duplicate user names you need to define a unique index on the 'USER' field.

Comment: Well, message could do,though I would have preferred the user to be excluded from the query. But ok. Nice. Thank you.

Comment: Despite the way the OP does the assignment to the Panel's text, I would do your comparison on a case-insensitive basis, e.g. using CompareText, otherwise it's a bit of an accident waiting to happen, if the assignment is changed later.

Comment: Indeed, do you want your usernames to be case sensitive?

Comment: It is not a good advice to misuse a gui control as a value container

Comment: actually another one of my queries holds the logged user so I just used the second part of suggested answer to compare. This way I am certain that it wont misfire.

Answer (score 4):

You should use a facade to handle such rules.

```
TNotifyUserEvent = procedure(Sender : TObject; const Username : string ) of object;

TFacade = class( TDataModule )
private
  FOnUserLogin : TNotifyUserEvent;
  FOnUserLogout : TNotifyUserEvent;
  FOnUserDeleted : TNotifyUserEvent;
  FUsername : string;
  procedure CheckLoggedIn;
public
  procedure Login( const Username, Password : string );
  procedure Logout;

  procedure DeleteUser( const Username : string );

  property Username : string read FUsername;
  property OnUserLogin : TNotifyUserEvent read FOnUserLogin write FOnUserLogout;
  property OnUserLogout : TNotifyUserEvent read FOnUserLogout write FOnUserLogout;
  property OnUserDeleted : TNotifyUserEvent read FOnUserDeleted write FOnUserDeleted;
end;

var
  Facade : TFacade;

procedure TFacade.DeleteUser( const Username : string );
begin
  // *** Verification Part ***
  // only logged in users are allowed
  CheckLoggedIn; 
  // if you have some user rights, you can check here
  // do not delete yourself
  if CompareText( Username, FUsername ) = 0 then
    raise Exception.Create( 'you cannot delete yourself' );
  // ** Execute Part ***
  DataModule1...
  // raise an exception if not successful      
  // *** Store State Part ***
  // *** Notification Part ***
  if Assigned( FOnUserDeleted ) then
    FOnUserDeleted( Self, Username );
end;

procedure TFacade.CheckLoggedIn;
begin
  if FUsername = '' then
    raise Exception.Create( 'you are not logged in' );
end;    

procedure TFacade.Login( const Username, Password : string );
begin
  // *** Verification Part ***
  if FUsername <> '' then
    Logout;
  // *** Execute Part ***
  if not DataModule1.RealLogin( Username, Passwordd ) then
    raise Exception.Create( 'you cannot login' );
  // *** Store State Part ***
  FUsername := Username;
  // *** Notification Part ***
  if Assigned( FOnUserLogin ) then
    FOnUserLogin( Self, Username );
end;

procedure Logout;
var
  LUsername : string; 
begin
  // *** Verification Part ***
  CheckLoggedIn;
  // *** Execute Part ***
  LUsername := FUsername;
  DataModule1....
  // *** Store State Part ***
  FUsername := '';
  // *** Notification Part ***
  if Assigned( FOnUserLogout ) then
    FOnUserLogout( Self, LUsername );
end;
```

The statusbar can be updated by reading the facade property (inside reacting to the events)

```
if Facade.Username = '' then
  StatusBar1.Panels[1].Text := '(not logged in)'
else
  StatusBar1.Panels[1].Text := Facade.Username;
```